# Yii2 after Action how to detect specific action in controller?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a controller with the action View

```
public function actionView($id)
    {   
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        if($request->isAjax){
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

            return [
                    'title'=> "Request #".$id,
                    'content'=>$this->renderAjax('view', [
                        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
                    ]),
                    'footer'=> Html::button('Close',['class'=>'btn btn-default pull-left','data-dismiss'=>"modal"])
                ];    
        }else{
            return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            ]);
        }
    }
```

And in my model, I have the after action method

```
 public function afterAction($action, $result)
    {
        $result = parent::afterAction($action, $result);

        if($action->id == 'view')
            file_put_contents('view.txt', 'test');
        else if($action == 'view')
            file_put_contents('view.txt', 'test');


        return $result;
    }
```

What I trying to do is I wanted to detect that the controller is the VIEW CONTROLLER. I tried above method but none of them worked. Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can access action ID by:

```
$action->id
```

Comment: This is correct answer - it does not work in OP's example because he placed `afterAction()` in a wrong place (model instead of controller).

Answer (score 0):

Controller ID is stored in

```
$action->controller->id
```

Comment: That's weird. If your controller is named `ViewController` in `afterAction()` `$action->controller->id` will be `view`.

Comment: hmm.. i think the after action function did not run at all. Any method to check whether the after Action is working?

Comment: First of all `afterAction()` to work properly must be placed in a controller or a module only otherwise is just some method named that way. You said you've got this in model.

Comment: I just wrote that it needs to be in a controller or a module.

Comment: Yeah it need to be place inside controller. Thanks @Bizley